# NSInvocation crashes the app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

My project is a calculation based criteria,where we populate list of mandatory fields from the `coredata` that were first fetched through webservice.

There is an option to calculate and reset the field. Since the calculation takes much time and freezes the app, I used `NSInvocationOperation` adding it to an `NSOperationQueue`.

Whenever I enter "calculate" an operation is being queued and with no time if a reset it ,the app crashes and the console shows that it has crashed at [RiskModel calculate],which is calling the queued operation.

Is there any better solution to do this function

```
- (void)calculateRiskAutomatically {
    [self.calculateOpQueue cancelAllOperations];
    NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(calculateRiskAutomaticallyWithOperation) object:nil];
    [self.calculateOpQueue addOperation:operation];
    [operation release];
}

- (void)calculateRiskAutomaticallyWithOperation {
    [self.riskModel calculate];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showOutput) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3590cfd8 objc_msgSend + 44
1   RiskCalculator      0x000135dc -[RiskModel calculate] (RiskModel.m:193)
2   RiskCalculator      0x0000895e -[RiskModelViewController calculateRiskAutomaticallyWithOperation] (RiskModelViewController.m:82)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x344fa80c __invoking___ + 60
4   CoreFoundation                  0x344557da -[NSInvocation invoke] + 154
5   Foundation                      0x32f4a698 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 108
6   Foundation                      0x32ee339c -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 856
7   Foundation                      0x32f4c79c __block_global_6 + 96
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x334f1d4e _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 6
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x334f4890 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 252
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x330941c8 _pthread_wqthread + 288
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3309409c start_wqthread + 0`
```

Comment: Can you show us the error message that displays when the app crashes

Comment: added the error in the question

Comment: What code is at RiskModel.m: line 193? And what is the exception message?

Comment: - (void)calculate {
    


    for (NSMutableDictionary *endPointData in self.endPointDataList) {

        double riskValue = [self calculateRiskForEndPoint:[endPointData objectForKey:@"endPoint"] procedureId:procedureId];
        [endPointData setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",riskValue] forKey:@"risk"];

    }

}